# Using JMock how do I mock an argument of Class<T>?

Tags: jmock

I am using jMock and I am confused as to how to mock an argument that I want to be any entityClass?

Here is the method I am trying to match:

```
public <T> List<T> find(Query query, Class<T> entityClass) { }
```

Here is what I got.  I want to match anything on the second parameter:

```
allowing(template).find(with(any(Query.class)), Foo.class);
```

which doesn't work since I used with on the first parameter.  I basically want to mock this method no matter what arguments are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to using the ignoring method to meet my needs:

```
ignoring(myTemplate);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to ignore that one method in your mock object, you could also write:

```
allowing(template).find(with(any(Query.class)), with(any(Class.class)));
```